# How do you set paperclip expiry header for aws that depends on the object's date attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Im using gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.5', and gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0' and i want to set expiry header for the object im saving. I am doing smth like this and this is working:

```
 has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "340x280#", small:  "200x200#", xs: "200x140#", thumb: "80x80#", original: "400x380#"},
                          s3_headers:{ 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=31557600', 'Expires' => 1.year.from_now.httpdate }
```

But now i want to do
      'Expires' => Model.start_date + 1.month instead of 1.year.from_now
But when i do it gives me undefined method error. I have also tried self.start_date and just start_date instead of Model.start_date, but the same error appears every time. I also tried to do

```
 def start_date_for_object
    return self.start_date + 1.month
 end
```

and then did: 
'Expires' => start_date_for_object
  but same error! Why cant i call the model attribute in there?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You are already setting cache-control.  It's not clear why you'd want to set expires as well, since that should make your object uncacheable once the expires time has past.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Would chase control delete the object from aws? It didnt seem obvious. BUT yeah, i want to delete the object from aws at a certain time based on object's start_date attribute. Thanks

Comment: I wondered if that was what you were thinking.  That's not what `Expires` does.  `Expires` is an HTTP header that tells browsers and itermediate caches when the object is expected to be obsolete and should no longer be cached -- similar to `Cache-Control` but deprecated and largely useless.  [`x-amz-expiration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) is a read-only *response* header that tells you when S3 is planning to purge an object because of a bucket lifecycle policy, but you can't ask S3 to delete an object at an arbitrary time in the future.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot for your help.